# Spark Array column - Find max interval between two values

Tags: scala, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, scala-spark

I have a **Scala Spark** **dataframe** with the **schema**:

```
    root
     |-- passengerId: string (nullable = true)
     |-- travelHist: array (nullable = true)
     |    |-- element: integer (containsNull = true)
```

I want to **iterate through the array elements and find the max number of occurrences of 0 values between 1 and 2**.

| passengerID | travelHist |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 1, 0 |
| 2 | 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 1, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0 |
| 3 | 0,0,0,2,1,0,2,1,0 |

The **output** for the above records should look like below:

| passengerID | maxStreak |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 7 |
| 2 | 3 |
| 3 | 1 |

What would be the most **efficient way to find such an interval** assuming the number of elements in the array does not exceed 50 values?

Comment: The answer could be even in Python. I can convert it to Scala syntax later.

Answer (score 3):

Let us do some pattern matching

```
df1 = (
    df
    .withColumn('matches', F.expr("array_join(travelHist, '')"))
    .withColumn('matches', F.expr("regexp_extract_all(matches, '1(0+)2', 1)"))
    .withColumn('matches', F.expr("transform(matches, x -> length(x))"))
    .withColumn('maxStreak', F.expr("array_max(matches)"))
)
```

---

```
df1.show()
+-----------+--------------------+-------+---------+
|passengerID|          travelHist|matches|maxStreak|
+-----------+--------------------+-------+---------+
|          1|[1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2...| [4, 7]|        7|
|          2|[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0...|    [3]|        3|
|          3|[0, 0, 0, 2, 1, 0...|    [1]|        1|
+-----------+--------------------+-------+---------+
```

Comment: Your answer is correct. Thanks for the help! However, I am on Spark version 2.4. It does not support regexp_extract_all() function. I am looking for an alternative way to get the same result in Scala.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a solution using scala UDF in pyspark. You can find the code for the UDF and release jar used in the pyspark script in the following repository.

https://github.com/dineshdharme/pyspark-native-udfs

Code for scala UDF is as follows.

```
package com.help.udf

import org.apache.spark.sql.api.java.UDF1

import scala.collection.mutable
import util.control.Breaks._
import scala.reflect.runtime.currentMirror
import scala.tools.reflect.ToolBox

class CountZeros extends UDF1[Array[Int], Int] {

  override def call(given_array: Array[Int]): Int = {


    //println("Printing all element")
    //given_array.foreach(ele => print (ele + ",  "))
    //println("adding the debug printing ")
    var maxCount = -1

    var runningCount = -1
    var insideLoop = false

    for( ele <- given_array ){

        if (ele == 1) {
          // initialize count to 0
          runningCount = 0
          insideLoop = true


        }
        if (ele == 0 && insideLoop) {
          runningCount += 1

        }
        if (ele == 2 && insideLoop) {
          insideLoop = false
          if (maxCount == -1) {
            maxCount = runningCount
          }
          if (runningCount > maxCount) {
            maxCount = runningCount
          }

        }



      //println( "ele ", ele, " maxCount  ", maxCount, "  runningCount  ", runningCount, " insideLoop flag  ", insideLoop)
    }


    //println("maxCount" , maxCount)
    maxCount
  }
}
```

Following is the pyspark code which uses the above UDF.

```
import sys

import pyspark.sql.functions as F
from pyspark import SparkContext, SQLContext
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql.types import *

spark = SparkSession.builder \
    .appName("MyApp") \
    .config("spark.jars", "file:/path/to/pyspark-native-udfs/releases/pyspark-native-udfs-assembly-0.1.2.jar") \
    .getOrCreate()

sc = spark.sparkContext
sqlContext = SQLContext(sc)


data1 = [
    [1, [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 1, 0]],
    [2, [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 1, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0]],
    [3, [0,0,0,2,1,0,2,1,0]],
]

df1Columns = ["passengerID", "travelHist"]
df1 = sqlContext.createDataFrame(data=data1, schema=df1Columns)
df1 = df1.withColumn("travelHist", F.col("travelHist").cast("array<int>"))

df1.show(n=100, truncate=False)
df1.printSchema()



spark.udf.registerJavaFunction("count_zeros_udf", "com.help.udf.CountZeros", IntegerType())

df1.createOrReplaceTempView("given_table")

df1_array = sqlContext.sql("select *, count_zeros_udf(travelHist) as maxStreak from given_table")
print("Dataframe after applying SCALA NATIVE UDF")
df1_array.show(n=100, truncate=False)
```

Output :

```
+-----------+------------------------------------------------------+
|passengerID|travelHist                                            |
+-----------+------------------------------------------------------+
|1          |[1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 1, 0]   |
|2          |[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 1, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0]|
|3          |[0, 0, 0, 2, 1, 0, 2, 1, 0]                           |
+-----------+------------------------------------------------------+

root
 |-- passengerID: long (nullable = true)
 |-- travelHist: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: integer (containsNull = true)

Dataframe after applying SCALA NATIVE UDF
+-----------+------------------------------------------------------+---------+
|passengerID|travelHist                                            |maxStreak|
+-----------+------------------------------------------------------+---------+
|1          |[1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 1, 0]   |7        |
|2          |[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 1, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0]|3        |
|3          |[0, 0, 0, 2, 1, 0, 2, 1, 0]                           |1        |
+-----------+------------------------------------------------------+---------+
```

Comment: Thank you! I am using Spark version 2.4 and it does not support regexp_extract_all(). The UDF mentioned above will work, but I am seeing if I can use findAllIn() instead. Does my syntax below look correct?


  val df1 = travel_hist.withColumn("matches", expr("array_join(travelHist, '')"))
    val pat = "1(0+)2".r

    val df = travel_hist.select("matches").map { (line:Row) =>
      (for {
        m <- pat.findAllIn(line("matches")).matchData
        g <- m.subgroups
      } yield (g)
        ).toList
    }

Comment: @Abishek : I would collect all the indices where 1 appears in one array. Similarly for 2. Now the difference between the adjacent indices where first index value is 1 and second index value is 2 should give me maxStreak. No need to do regex matching.